# Node+MongoDB - Error: process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi I am getting the following error when i run my app.js. Unable to resolve the issue. Can someone help me

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                          ^
WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error index: instance.instancesmodels.$PublicDnsName_1 dup key: { : \"\" }","op":{"PublicDnsName":"","instanceId":"i-d9ff937a","reservationId":"r-60e814b6","name":"adhoc s1","region":"us-east-1b","status":"stopped","net_io":"","cpu_usage":"","_id":"56a9c6d1e86e8bff040644cb","isInUse":false,"__v":0}})
at Function.MongoError.create (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
at toError (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:114:22)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:597:23
at handleCallback (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:470:9
at handleCallback (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
at resultHandler (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:417:5)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:780:13
at [object Object].Callbacks.emit (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
at [object Object].messageHandler (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:249:23)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/simplehacker/simplehacker-us/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:265:22)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is on your second line: WriteError:

```
WriteError({
  "code": 11000,
  "index": 0,
  "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error index: instance.instancesmodels.$PublicDnsName_1 dup key: { : \"\" }",
  "op": {
    "PublicDnsName": "",
    "instanceId": "i-d9ff937a",
    "reservationId": "r-60e814b6",
    "name": "adhoc s1",
    "region": "us-east-1b",
    "status": "stopped",
    "net_io": "",
    "cpu_usage": "",
    "_id": "56a9c6d1e86e8bff040644cb",
    "isInUse": false,
    "__v": 0
  }
})
```

This index does not allow the write: `instance.instancesmodels.$PublicDnsName_1`.
It seems that you're inserting duplicate `PublicDnsName` (which in your case is an empty string).

You either have to remove the `unique` flag from the `PublicDnsName` index, or allow for a sparse index and then leave null values when there's no name.

Depending on what drivers you use, ORMs, such as mongoose and similar, you can resolve it on the app level or on the database level.

Comment: Glad to help if I can.